# Pandas: How to tackle varying number of columns when reading a pipe delimited file

Tags: python, pandas

I have stumbled upon a problem for which apparently I have not found any credible solution so far. I have a .txt file in 'pipe delimited' format as follows.

```
  GUEST_NAME    PROFILE_ID   FULL_ADD             IS_TOTAL   P_MONTH
  ANDREW J      223345       ANNA BUILDING,       2335       01-APR-2019  
                             327 PERIAR, CHENNAI
  P BASU        334567       Times Square, 
                             Level 2 B Wing,  
                             Andheri Kurla Road   Mumbai      400059     4335    31-AUG-2019
```

The above is just a snippet.

As you can see the 2nd row is 'bulging out' and two  more columns are created. When I read this .txt using `pandas`, I am getting the error as given below.

```
df = pd.read_csv('path to txt file\file.txt',sep='|')
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 2, 
saw 7
```

In order to tackle this I found two possible way outs

1. Use `error_bad_lines` in `pd.read_csv()` - This will remove the 2nd row. This is not wanted
2. Use the following reading method

   `df = pd.read_csv(filepath\file.txt',sep='|',names=list(range(0,7)))`
   This is also not a great solution as it creates 2 more columns.

What I am looking for is a way around through which those 'bulged row(s)' are fitted inside the right column. Considering the above example, the resultant `df` should look like

```
GUEST_NAME    PROFILE_ID   FULL_ADD                IS_TOTAL   P_MONTH
  ANDREW J      223345       ANNA BUILDING,         2335     01-APR-2019  
                             327 PERIAR, CHENNAI
  P BASU        334567       Times Square, 
                             Level 2 B Wing,  
                             Andheri Kurla Road   
                             Mumbai 400059          4335    31-AUG-2019
```

Any clue on how to achieve this? Please note in actual there are 100 columns and the above 'bulging out' can happen to any columns with `string` contents.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue a while ago, and found that following advice [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11493) helped, specifically, to specifically the engine=python; so might be worth maybe just trying:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename,header=None,engine='python',sep='|')
```

...i know this might not be the optimal answer, just letting you know what worked for me.

Another way I've gotten around this previously is I found if I save the file in excel format, and use pd.read_excel instead of pd.read_csv there weren't problems (even though I agree that that shouldn't really make a difference, again just something that worked for me for these kinds of things before).

Comment: Still I am getting the error as `ParserError: Expected 100 fields in line 126, saw 102`.